# Xamarin blue tooth keyboard behaves differently from virtual

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

In Android I have set EditText to `android:inputType="textCapWords"`, this works fine on a virtual keyboard but once connected to a blue tooth keyboard it will not capitalize words unless holding down shift or pressing the caps lock. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: What driver are you using for the keyboard?  Make sure you are using the vendor keyboard driver and not the standard keyboard driver.

Comment: How would I go about doing something like that?